# Method doesn't return double and variable isnt initialized whilst variable is delcared

Tags: java

```
 public static double calculation(){
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                int hours;
                double charge;
                String disabled;
                disabled = scanner.nextLine();
                if (disabled.equals("Yes")){
                     System.out.println("Parking is free");   
                }
                if (disabled.equals("No")){
                    hours = scanner.nextInt();
                    if (hours == 1){
                        charge = 1.00;
                        return charge;
                    } 
                    if (hours >=2 && hours <= 4){
                        charge = 4.00;
                        return charge;
                    }
   
                    if (hours >=5 && hours <=6){
                        charge = 4.50;
                        return charge;
                    }
                    
   
                   if (hours >= 7 && hours <=8){
                       charge = 5.50;
                       return charge;
                    } 
                
                    }
               
   }
```

**Gives the error code that method must return type double**

```
 import java.util.Scanner; 

 class parking 
 {
   public static void main (String [] a)
     {
         all(); 
         System.exit(0);
}
public static double local_l(){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Do you live locally ? (Yes or No)");
           String local;
           double deduction1;
           local = scanner.nextLine();
           if (local.equals("Yes")){
              deduction1 = 1.0;
              return deduction1;
           }
           if (local.equals("No")){
              deduction1 = 0;
              return deduction1;
           }
           else{
              System.out.println("Invalid answer, please answer : Yes or No (exactly as written)");
              
           }
           return 0.0;
    }
           
   public static double calculation(){
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                int hours;
                double charge;
                String disabled;
                disabled = scanner.nextLine();
                if (disabled.equals("Yes")){
                     System.out.println("Parking is free");   
                }
                if (disabled.equals("No")){
                    hours = scanner.nextInt();
                    if (hours == 1){
                        charge = 1.00;
                        return charge;
                    } 
                    if (hours >=2 && hours <= 4){
                        charge = 4.00;
                        return charge;
                    }
   
                    if (hours >=5 && hours <=6){
                        charge = 4.50;
                        return charge;
                    }
                    
   
                   if (hours >= 7 && hours <=8){
                       charge = 5.50;
                       return charge;
                    } 
                
                    }
               
   }
   public static double old_age_pensioner (double charge, double deduction1,double deduction2){
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           String oap;
           System.out.println("Are you an old age pensioner? ");
           oap = scanner.nextLine();
           if(oap.equals("Yes")){
              deduction2 = 2.0;
              return deduction2;
           }
           if (oap.equals("No")){
              deduction2 = 0; 
              return deduction2;
           }
           else {
              System.out.println("Invalid answer, please answer : Yes or No (exactly as written");
              
   
           }
    
       double result;
       result = charge - deduction1 - deduction2; 
       System.out.println("The parking charge is" + result);
       return 0;
   }
   public static void all(){
          double charge = calculation();
          double deduction1 = local_l();
          double deduction2 = old_age_pensioner(charge, deduction1, deduction2);
   }
```

}

**The local variable deduction2 may not have been initialized in all functions. I'm very new to java and passing arguments to share variables is a tricky part for me. For my assignment, i cant use global variables.

Any comments on the code are appreicted**

Comment: What will it return if `if (disabled.equals("No")){` is false? Or if `hours < 1` or `hours > 8`? You need to ensure that every possible path of execution returns something.

Answer (score 1):

your `calculation` method should not compile as it does not cover all the cases if else cases. Method has to return double values for all possible execution paths.

Use an IDE for java development like IntellijIdea or Eclipse. You will avoid these issues easily. Notice the cases you missed.

```
public static double calculation(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int hours;
    double charge;
    String disabled;
    disabled = scanner.nextLine();
    if (disabled.equals("Yes")){
            System.out.println("Parking is free");
            return 0.0; // missed return statement
    }
    if (disabled.equals("No")){
        hours =scanner.nextInt();
        if (hours == 1){
            charge = 1.00;
            return charge;
        } 
        if (hours >=2 && hours <= 4){
            charge = 4.00;
            return charge;
        }

        if (hours >=5 && hours <=6){
            charge = 4.50;
            return charge;
        }
        

        if (hours >= 7 && hours <=8){
            charge = 5.50;
            return charge;
        } 
        else {return some_double_value; // missed return statement
        }  
    
    }
    else {return some_double_value; // missed return statement
    }   
        
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).